# Spring Boot custom health indicator not showing up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I believe followed almost all tutorials on the Internet and read many SO answers and still I'm stuck.

#### 1. A simple health check

```java
@Component
public class HealthCheck implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return Health.up().build();
    }

}
```

#### 2. Application.yaml is configured to show all details:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*"
management.endpoint.health.show-details: ALWAYS
```

#### 3. Spring-boot-actuator included as dependency:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

#### 4. Spring boot of recent release:

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.RELEASE'
```

#### 5. Main application class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` (which implicitly brings `@ComponentScan`).

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class PaymentServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PaymentServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My custom health check has to test for Apache Kafka, but I skipped the details for brevity. 
Still, invoking `/actuator/health` endpoint I get the same default result:

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "components": {
        "diskSpace": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "total": 250685575168,
                "free": 99168997376,
                "threshold": 10485760
            }
        },
        "ping": {
            "status": "UP"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I may have missed?

Comment: i tried it and the health endpoint is used. Could you make a system.out. there and try it again... if there is something in the console.

Comment: Verify the component is actually configured as a spring bean. Just annotating as @Component does not guarantee it becomes a bean if there's no component scan for it.

Comment: @Compass, I've updated the question. The main class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, which enables component scan.

Comment: Your HealthIndicator class doesn't add any extra information.

Comment: add a name to your component like @Component("healtCheck").

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, but am not sure about the cause. The class was indeed not registered as bean, and surprisingly, adding explicitly base packages attribute helped:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.example.*")
```

Interesting that there was no need to do the above in a different project.

Comment: The default ComponentScan will scan based on the Spring Boot Application's package path, and its subdirectories, but not anything above it hierarchically. Depending on your package arrangement this is a very likely cause, i.e. if you have a sub-application.

Answer (score 2):

This is solved by adding this code:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

However, it creates another problem. When calling /actuator/health endpoint, you see all the details which is problematic for me. What I want to achieve is to see only statuses for both endpoints.

Comment: you can expose only specific endpoints by adding property `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=endpoint1,endpoint2` where `endpoint1` and `endpoint2` contains a list of endpoints to expose with a commas between them. see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuator-enable-endpoints#2-exposing-specific-endpoints)

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly the base package for the HealthIndicator is not recognized by the application container instead of declaring the class as @component Stereotype.

Fix for the issue- declare base package of HealthIndicator in Main Spring boot application class:
@SpringBootApplication (scanBasePackages = "basepackage for your class HealthCheck")
public class PaymentServiceApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PaymentServiceApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

EDIT : NOTE- The above declaration of base package="" is not main spring boot class is not necessary.

You must stop the SERVER and then clean build the maven application and RESTART the server and re-run the application

You can now run find your custom health endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter issue too, what I miss is

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.example.*")
```

You can instead define your packages to scan

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example", "com.other"}
```

I will note I tested using scanBasepackages as described in the top answer and that doesn't seem to work if you also have the @ComponentScan defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you have packages structure like:

```
com.example.health.MyHealthIndicator
com.example.myapp.MyApp (SpringApplication.run() is here)
```

then MyHealthIndicator will not be treated as component. In this case in MyApp you should add scanBasePackages

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.example.*")
public class MyApp { ... }
```

BUT if you put your component inside package where application is, then scanBasePackages is not needed:

```
com.example.myapp.health.MyHealthIndicator
com.example.myapp.MyApp
```

Spring will automatically find all components inside com.example.myapp.* packages. And it will not search outside of this package, unless you ask him to do so via scanBasePackages parameter.